# What is a block device?

Tags: dual-boot, devices

I am creating dual-boot system with Windows 7 and Ubuntu. I want to check Windows 7 installation block device.

What is block device? How to distinguish the Windows 7 installation block device from Ubuntu?

How can we make secure that the Windows block device cannot be deleted by root user?

Answer (score 6):

Any device that allows reading or writing data blocks is a *"Block Device"*. In Ubuntu hard drives are represented by their drivers either as `/hdX` for an IDE drive or `/sdX` for a SCSI (or SATA in a modern system) drive.

The `X` stands for an alphabetic letter starting with `a` for the first device. The first hard drive in your system will therefore be `/sda`, the second drive `/sdb` etc.. Partitions on that device are further numbered. The first partition on the first drive is `/sda1`, the third partition on the third drive `/sdc3` etc.

To list the representation, UUID and TYPE of all block devices in our system we may issue:

```
sudo blkid
sudo lsblk
```

This, in combination with the following command to give further details on partitions

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

should give us enough information to find out the location of our Windows, or Ubuntu installation.

Throughout information on how we boot is given with the [Boot Info Script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/).

To answer your additional question: **root can do anything**. Therefore it is no way other than unplugging the drive to prevent root from overwriting a Windows partition.

Comment: Also `sudo lsblk` list block devices

Answer (score 0):

### What is a block device?

A block device is a consistent interface to a device that resembles a readable, easily seekable (compared to tape drives), possibly writable non-volatile storage. This include real non-volatile storage devices like ATA and SCSI drives (`/dev/sda`), subdivisions of such devices like NVMe namespaces (`/dev/nvme0n1`) and partitions (`/dev/sda1`), and many others like device mapper (LVM, LUKS etc.) volumes (`/dev/mapper/linux`, `/dev/dm-0`), loopback mappings of disk/filesystem images (`/dev/loop0`), and virtual disks (`/dev/vda`). Block devices allow direct, easy manipulation of the underlying data through standard calls like [read](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/read.2.html)(2), [write](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/write.2.html)(2) and [mount](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mount.2.html)(2). This is different from character devices in Linux, a lot of which speaks class-specific custom formats.

A block device can be identified by using `ls -l` on a file, with the leading character `b` denoting that it is a block device:

```
$ ls -l /dev/sda
brw-rw---- root disk 8, 0 Jan  1 00:00 /dev/sda
```

or by using `stat`, which shows the file as a "block special file":

```
  File: /dev/sda
  Size: 0               Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   block special file
Device: 0,5     Inode: 164         Links: 1     Device type: 8,0
Access: (0660/brw-rw----)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (    6/    disk)
```

A list of online block devices can be get using `lsblk`:

```
$ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINTS
sda           8:0    0   240G  0 disk  
├─sda1        8:1    0   128M  0 part  /boot/efi
├─sda2        8:2    0     4G  0 part  [SWAP]
└─sda3        8:3    0 235.9G  0 part  /
```

Details of a block device, like its UUID and label, can be obtained by running `blkid` with the correct privileges:

```
# blkid /dev/nvme0n1p1
/dev/nvme0n1p1: LABEL_FATBOOT="ESP" LABEL="ESP"
UUID="1234-5678" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat"
PARTLABEL="EFI system partition"
PARTUUID="43465c49-75a0-4ff3-ac18-bbd4a4ca372b"
```

### Where is my Windows?

By using `lsblk`, `blkid` and (with the correct drivers present) `mount -o ro`, you can get enough information to find out the location of Windows or Ubuntu. Almost all Windows desktop has their OS in an NTFS partition, and the existence of a folder named `Windows` in the root of such filesystems is often a giveaway.

### How to hide my Windows from most people?

It is safe to delete any unmounted block devices. Block devices are not real hardware, but magical gates: you create the gate with the right major and minor numbers, and the gate to your disk magically opens.

Because block devices are magical gates, deleting a block device only wipes the gate from existence; the actual data is untouched.

```
# b2sum /dev/sda1
# rm /dev/sda1
# mknod -m 0660 /dev/sda1 b 8 1
# chown root:disk /dev/sda1
# b2sum /dev/sda1
```

### How to hide my Windows from even root?

Unfortunately the above can't really hide anything from root. Even if you remove it from `/dev`, by creating a device with the right numbers it will magically come back:

```
# mknod -m 0660 /dev/sda3 b 8 3
```

The only way to fully hide its existence and prevent its overwriting is to either unplug the Windows drive, or to unload and delete whatever driver stack driving the disk with Windows.